# CSS3 Dont show DIV if screen size is larger than x

Tags: html, css

So I have managed to get the following code working:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .hide {
        display: none !important;
    }

}
```

This makes sure the div with class 'hide' will not show if unless it is `1024px`.

How would I be able to make it the opposite (so it will show  if the screen is below a particular size then hide if the screen is larger)?

I've tried looking through multiple pages of tutorials etc. but could not find a working answer.

Comment: Did you try `min-width`?

Answer (score 3):

You can try this: http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/GCu2D/174/

CSS:

```
div {
    border:1px solid green;
    padding:10px;
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
    #my-content {
        display: block;
    }
    /* show it on small screens */
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 2048px) {
    #my-content {
        display: none;
    }
    /* hide it elsewhere */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="my-content"></div>
```

You can play around with the `max-width` and `min-width` for desired effect

Answer (score 1):

Kamlesh answer is correct, however you should use `display: initial` or `display: inherit` instead of display: block as these will not mess with span elements for example which `display: block` might do.

Answer (score 0):

Max width means that rule will *not* be triggered above that width. Min-width means the rule will not be triggered below that width. If you want something to show up at a certain width and greater, use min-width.

Example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width:992px) {
  .hide (display: none;) // means that element with class 'hide' will be hidden at 992 pixels and above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

show if < 1000px!!!!!!!

```js
                        winW = $(window).width();
                        $("#px").html(winW);
                        if(winW>1000){
                        $(".foo").hide();
                        }else{
                        $(".foo").show();
                        }
                        $(window).resize(function () {
                        winW = $(window).width();
                        $("#px").html(winW);
                        if(winW>1000){
                        $(".foo").hide();
                        }else{
                        $(".foo").show();
                        }
                        });
```

```css
         .foo{
             height: auto;
             margin-top: 70px;
             border: 2px solid #E3E3E3;
             border-radius: 19px
         }
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body> show if &lt; 1000px!!!!!!!
        <div class="foo" >
           <h1><center> show if &lt; 1000px   </h1>
        </div>

        <p id="px">
        </p>

    </body>
</html>
```